# Using virtualenv on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, virtualenv, jupyter

I trying to use `virtualenv` on jupyter notebook, to use all packages installed in an environment, but inside jupyter they are not recognized.

Already tried:

```
pip install tornado==4.5.3
pip install ipykernel==4.8.2
```

What I do is:
Initializing the environment on prompt (windows 7):
Move to directory of environment: `cd C:\Python\Envs\env1\Scripts`
and use: `activate` now the promt show (env1), so it's active.

From there, I move to another directory and call jupyter, but when starts, the package installed on envoriment are not callable.

How we can active the environment on jupyter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe you should install an *ipykernel* inside your venv first.

1. `virtualenv .venv`
2. `.venv\Scripts\activate.bat` to activate the venv.
3. `python -m pip install ipykernel`
4. `python -m ipykernel install --user --name .venv` to install a new kernel named `.venv`.
5. `jupyter notebook` here and you can select your new kernel.

REFERENCE: [Kernels for different environments](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments)

Comment: I had to use `python -m ipykernel` instead of `ipykernel` from the command line.

Comment: @rudolfbyker That's fine. Adding a `python -m` prefix will be safer.

Comment: No, I mean `ipykernel` was not found on the path, even when the venv is activated.

Comment: The reference documentation mentioned suggests `python -m ipykernel`, there are no mentions of `ipykernel` as a shell command (anymore?).

Answer (score 24):

for Mac OS/Linux users:

```
python -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate
pip install jupyter
ipython kernel install --user --name=venv
jupyter notebook
```