# Jupyter notebook not recognizing packages in venv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pip, jupyter-notebook

This has been driving me crazy. For some reason it seems like my .ipynb file doesn't recognize the python packages in my venv. I get this error even though I've clearly installed opencv. I run into this exact same problem for dlib and imutils too.

[image]

**However,** when I use opevcv in a regular .py file in the save venv, it works completely fine so it's something to do with .ipynb (Jupiter Notebooks).

I have tried `pip3 install opencv-python`

**Note:** I am pretty sure I have selected the correct venv when running my .ipynb file.

The output I get when I run `!pip list` in the Jupyter Notebook (which includes opencv-python):

```
Package                 Version
----------------------- -------------------
absl-py                 0.12.0
astunparse              1.6.3
cachetools              4.2.1
certifi                 2020.12.5
chardet                 4.0.0
cmake                   3.18.4.post1
cycler                  0.10.0
dlib                    19.22.0
flatbuffers             1.12
gast                    0.4.0
google-auth             1.29.0
google-auth-oauthlib    0.4.4
google-pasta            0.2.0
grpcio                  1.34.1
h5py                    3.1.0
idna                    2.10
imutils                 0.5.4
keras-nightly           2.5.0.dev2021032900
Keras-Preprocessing     1.1.2
kiwisolver              1.3.1
Markdown                3.3.4
matplotlib              3.4.1
numpy                   1.19.5
oauthlib                3.1.0
opencv-python           4.5.1.48
opt-einsum              3.3.0
Pillow                  8.2.0
pip                     21.0.1
protobuf                3.15.8
pyasn1                  0.4.8
pyasn1-modules          0.2.8
pyparsing               2.4.7
python-dateutil         2.8.1
requests                2.25.1
requests-oauthlib       1.3.0
rsa                     4.7.2
setuptools              54.1.2
six                     1.15.0
tensorboard             2.5.0
tensorboard-data-server 0.6.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit  1.8.0
tensorflow              2.5.0rc1
tensorflow-estimator    2.5.0rc0
termcolor               1.1.0
typing-extensions       3.7.4.3
urllib3                 1.26.4
Werkzeug                1.0.1
wheel                   0.36.2
wrapt                   1.12.1
```

**Please help, thank you**

Comment: did you add the venv into the notebook kernel?

Comment: check it out. https://janakiev.com/blog/jupyter-virtual-envs/

Comment: Yes I ran this command with my venv `ipython kernel install --user --name=.venv`

Comment: the pip list cmd may run inside the global python env, because it is not the python command, it is just a shell cmd, did you select the right kernel in the notebook kernel dropdown list?

Comment: ok, if you activate venv in the terminal and open a python repl, can you import the cv package? maybe the installation is in the incorrect env

Comment: Yes, it works fine when I activate the venv and run import cv2 in a python repl

Comment: what about `!which python` result in the notebook?

Comment: When I run it in my Jupyter Notebook it gives me the correct path `Documents/Projects/Personal/Clear Path/backend/env/bin/python` my venv name is env

Comment: I'm so sorry, it worked after I followed your first step. I first created the venv with virtualenv, but I recreated the venv with python3 -m venv env and this worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this question will be deleted but this is what fixed it for me (thanks to @Shi XiuFeng):

I had initially created my venv with `virtualenv env` which didn't work, and so when I recreated the venv with `python3 -m venv env` this worked completely fine.

Comment: ok, no sweat, python venv management is always very hard to debug.

Answer (score 3):

Are you using your local machine? How do you fire up the jupyter notebook? You could try the following:

1. Open a prompt and activate your virtual environment.
2. `python` And then `>>> import <module>`: Does it import it?

Make sure that you have jupyter insatlled in that environment and then

1. Open a prompt and activate your virtual environment.
2. Issue `python -m jupyter notebook`

Comment: Yes the first part works, when I go into my venv, and run python in the shell I can import cv2 no problem. For the second part, when I run `python -m jupyter notebook` I get `venv/bin/python: No module named jupyter`, am I missing something? Do I need to install Jupiter?

Comment: However, I can run `jupyter notebook` just itself to start the server without any errors

Comment: Yes, you have to install jupyter inside the venv, and launch the jupyter notebook from whithin that venv. Activate your venv, and `python -m pip install jupyter`, then `python -m jupyter notebook`. The `python -m` part runs the provided module as a script. In my experience using conda, it eliminates many issues with modules. Without it, for example, you might `jupyter notebook` and end up with a jupyter kernel from your (base) environment.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that jupyter notebook is not using "virtualenv". Try following commands to run ipython/jupyter on current/active virtual environment as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55448424/7768504)

1. `source env/bin/activate`
2. `pip install ipykernel`
3. `ipython kernel install --user --name <venV>`
4. `ipython` or `jupyter notebook`

If you run into errors try resetting cache of command line using `hash -r`

Answer (score 0):

Try [changing kernels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGBoR.png). (Check on the image in the URL for guidance). If your venv is not in the list, you should add it manually. Follow [this guide to add your venv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39604271/conda-environments-not-showing-up-in-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: Thanks, I have actually already created a new venv and running the kernel in that venv, should I still switch to another kernel?

Answer (score 0):

I have Jupyter installed globally which led to the above issues when using it inside a virtual environment.

The following steps resolved the issue:

source ./bin/activate  (run from the venv directory)

python3 -m pip install jupyter

python3 -m notebook

start a new Notebook using the "Python3 (ipykernel)" from the dropdown.